# Kubernetes Loadbalancer External IP expose to only specific cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine, amazon-eks

I have setup the Loadbalancer service in kubernetes cluster. It's providing external IP address. I need to access that IP only from another cluster and restrict external IP access from anywhere. So that it can accessed only from two places, own cluster and another cluster.

Comment: Hope your requirement can be solved using firewall rules

Comment: @DineshBalasubramanian I have used loadBalancerSourceRanges. but im not able to get address range of the cluster from where I will access service.

Answer (score 1):

I have used loadBalancerSourceRanges to filter the range and specified the IPs of another cluster instances. It worked.